# Output of .php file upload script posted on form page

Tags: php, json

I have been asked to write a script which uploads a file to a webserver and then displays the output messages underneath the form that you use to select the file to upload. I am having trouble with getting the output messages to display. Relevant html form and javascript follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#fileuploader').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // e.preventDefault() for prevent form submisson with page reload
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "genericuploader.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#message_post").prepend(html);
            close_box();
        }
    });

});
});
</script>

<form id="fileuploader" action="genericuploader.php" method="post">
        Select a file to upload: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
        <select name='department'>
            <option value="0">Select a Department</option>
            <option value="D1">Department 1</option>
            <option value="D2">Department 2</option>
            <option value="D3">Department 3</option>
            <option value="D4">Department 4</option>
            <option value="D5">Department 5</option>
            <option value="D6">Department 6</option>
        </select> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    <div id="message_post"></div>
```

My php script is as follows:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// print_r($_FILES);

$return_json = '';
$filename = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
$filetmploc = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name']; 
$uploaded_type = $_FILES["uploaded"]["type"];

$uploaded_size = $_FILES['uploaded']['size'];
$target = $_POST['department'];
$pathandname = $target . "/" . $filename;

function make_dir($target){
if (!is_file($target) && !is_dir($target)) {  
    mkdir($target, 0777);  
    $return_json = json_encode('The directory ' . $target . ' was successfully created.');  
} else {  
    $return_json = json_encode('The directory ' . $target . ' exists');
}
return $return_json;
}


function uploadfile($tar, $temploc, $pathandname, $filename){
make_dir($tar);
//If everything is ok we try to upload it
if(move_uploaded_file($temploc, $pathandname)) { 
    $return_json = json_encode('The file '. $filename . ' has been uploaded'); 
} else { 
    $return_json = json_encode('Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.'); 
}
return $return_json;
}

if (!($uploaded_size > 0)) {
$return_json = json_encode('Select a file to upload.');
} else {
if ($uploaded_size > 10485760) {
    $return_json = json_encode('Your file is to big. The limit is 10 MB.');
} else {
    switch($uploaded_type) {
        case "application/application/vnd.ms-excel": //.xls
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
        case "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12": //.xlsm
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
        case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation": //.ppt
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
        case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation": //.pptx
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
        case "application/msword": //.doc
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
        case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document": //.docx
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
        case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet": //.xlsx
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
        case "application/vnd.visio": //.vsd
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
        case "application/pdf": //.pdf
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
       case "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation": //.odp
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
        case "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": //.ods
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
        case "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text": //.odt
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
        case "text/plain": //.txt
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;
        case "application/rtf": //.rtf
            $return_json = uploadfile($target, $filetmploc, $pathandname, $filename);
            break;  
        default: 
            $return_json = json_encode('You tried to upload an invalid filetype. <br>Supported filetypes: .xls, .xlsm, .ppt, .pptx, .doc, .docx, .xlsx, .vsd, .pdf, .odp, .ods, .odt, .txt, and .rtf.');
    }
}
echo $return_json;
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't do file upload with ajax, you'll need some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this technique](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v525/) to do file uploads in the background. Uses apc.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasn't clearer to start with, I am not having issues with actually uploading the file, that works. 

What I haven't been able to do is get the success or failure messages to show up on the same page as the upload form after hitting the submit button.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is the success handler ever actually executed?